# Detecting voice call support in mobile devices

Tags: mobile, tablet, voice, phone-call

When developing a mobile website, I want to display features based upon device capabilities.  Specifically, I want to have a "Call us" button that uses the "tel:" protocol (e.g. tel:5551234) to initiate a phone call.

However, not all mobile devices support phone calls, such as the iPad.

How can I programmatically (either server or client side) **determine whether a mobile user agent supports voice calling**?  I'm trying to avoid blacklisting based on user agent for maintainability reasons.

Comment: You could use [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/), it is opensource and there is apis for many languages.